# Hash and array with Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a .plist file that can be seen by Data::Dumper into this form

```
$VAR1 = {
          'SPOOLS' => [
                        'SPOOL1',
                        'SPOOL2',
                        'SPOOL3'
                      ],
          'path' => '/usr/local/thanks/for/your/help',
          'contentMatch' => [
                              {
                                'priority' => '1',
                                'match' => '*.hello'
                              },
                              {
                                'match' => '*.guys',
                                'priority' => '2'
                              }
                            ]
        };
```

To access my .plist file in Perl, I use this code:

```
my $locPlist = "conf.plist";

my $configdict = NSDictionary->dictionaryWithContentsOfFile_($locPlist);
my $plistref   = Foundation::perlRefFromObjectRef($configdict);
my %plist = %{$plistref};
```

I know how to access the "path" with "$plist{path}" and the SPOOLS array with "$plist{SPOOLS}[0]" but:
How can I get the of SPOOLS into an array, something like `my @array = $plist{SPOOLS}` and how can I also get the content of "contentMatch" ?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
Thank you so much for your help, I was able to access the data. But is there a cleaner way to get back the content from contentMatch in a hash and access directly instead of doing that:

```
my $number_matches = scalar @{ $plistref->{contentMatch} } ;
my $a = 0;
my %events;
foreach ( @{ $plistref->{contentMatch} } ) {
    $events{match}[$a] = $_->{match};
    $events{priority}[$a] = $_->{priority};

    $a = $a+1;
}
```

Best,
Tim.

Comment: Why not just use references instead of fussing over the exact type?

Comment: `my @array = @{$plist{SPOOLS}}`

Comment: @Thomas Please don't deface your question by editing it to say that it "should be deleted". Please contact a Stack Overflow moderator if you have an issue which requires this content to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my @spools = @{ $plistref->{SPOOLS} };

my @content_match = @{ $plistref->{contentMatch} };
```

Or, to dig a little deeper into the `contentMatch` example:

```
foreach ( @{ $plistref->{contentMatch} } ) {
  say "match: $_->{match}";
  say "priority: $_->{priority}";
}
```

Plenty more information about dealing with complex data structures in Perl in the [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

**Update:** You ask for help accessing the contentMatch data in another way. I'm not really sure what you're asking - all your sample code seems to do is to transpose an array of hashes into a hash of arrays. And I think that the array of hashes is a much better representation of of the data.

But it's your code and your data. So I think this is how I'd write what you're trying to do.

```
my %events;
foreach ( @{ $plistref->{contentMatch} } ) {
  push @{ $events{match} }, $_->{match};
  push @{ $events{priority}, $_->{priority};
}
```

I'd be far happier keeping it as an array of hashes, and I've already given you that code.

```
my @content_match = @{ $plistref->{contentMatch} };
```

I think that understanding how complex data structures work in Perl is crucial to becoming a competent Perl programmer. I highly recommend getting to grips with the examples in [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, one last question, is there a cleaner way to get back the content from contentMatch in a hash and access directly instead of doing that :

Comment: my $a = 0;
 my %events;
 foreach ( @{ $plistref->{contentMatch} } ) {
   $events{match}[$a] = $_->{match};
   $events{priority}[$a] = $_->{priority};

   print $events{match}[$a];
   print $events{priority}[$a];

   $a = $a+1;
 }

Comment: It's almost impossible to understand code like that in a comment. Please add this to your question. Or (probably better) ask a new question.

Comment: whoops, very sorry, I didn't realize it put the code in a one liner. I ve edited my post